# Jenkins Plugin failure error

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm getting failure message on adding Plugin , will anybody tell me why I'm getting this error:

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/credentials/2.1.4/credentials.hpi (redirected to: http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/software/jenkins/plugins/credentials/2.1.4/credentials.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:822)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1184)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1365)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Inconsistent file length: expected 928684 but only got 884511
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:805)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 2):

That's caused by [Jenkins redirects bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38340). I install this plugin by manually downloading the hpi from redirect url, then upload this hpi to Manage Plugins -> Advanced -> Upload Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error with few plugins upgrades as well.

A workaround is to **download it manually** (the plugin jpi/hpi file link to download should be listed in that error message). Even manually it sometimes fails to be downloaded (for me in Firefox, so I use a Download Manager, or IE browser instead).

1. Once downloaded - Save the the *.hpi / *.jpi file into the $JENKINS_HOME/plugins directory.
2. Rename the previous plugin, even if it has defferent extention (e.g, downloding github.hpi, and having github.jpi, I still rename it to github.jpi.old)
3. Restart Jenkins (allthough some plugins does not require restart)

Comment: I have had the exact same issue, and when I use wget, I notice that it takes a very long time to follow the redirect, Does anyone know if there is a timeout setting for plugin install whcih can be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar problem.

I'm running Jenkins on AWS EC2. I simply rebooted the instance and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in JDK 11: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213202

I came across the same issue.

After which, I uninstalled it and installed it back with **JDK8 u322-b06** (https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8) and the issue was fixed.

Alternatively, you can switch the Java version in jenkins.xml as:

```xml
  <executable>C:\Java\jdk8u322-b06\\bin\java.exe</executable>
```